# Binding property from Object in v-model

Tags: vue.js, vue-component

I have the following code, but when I render the page, I get the correct number of checkboxes with nulls beside them.  I'm guessing this has to do with how I set up my v-model.  My Business Lines array is returning as **{id: 1, name: Cars}, {id: 2, name: Trucks}, {id: 3, name: Buses}, etc...**

Here is a screenshot of what I'm seeing:[image]

Here's the code:

```
<b-dropdown text="Business Lines" variant="outline-dark" size="sm" class="filter-dropdown">
  <b-form-checkbox-group stacked size="sm" class="ml-2"
    v-model="formData.selectedBusinessLines"
    :options="formData.businessLines"                        
    >                        
  </b-form-checkbox-group>
</b-dropdown>
```

How do I set it up so that I can populate my control with objects but use the name property?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

***Two ways to get rid from the problem you are facing :***

1. Use `value-field` and `text-field` attributes in your `<b-form-checkbox-group>` element.

   Live Demo **:**

   ```js
   new Vue({  
     el: '#app',
     data() {
       return {
         formData: {
           selectedBusinessLines: [],
           businessLines: [
             {id: 1, name: 'Cars'},
             {id: 2, name: 'Trucks'}, 
             {id: 3, name: 'Buses'}
           ]
         }  
       }
     }            
   })
   ```

   ```html
   <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.3/vue.min.js"></script>
   <script src="https://unpkg.com/bootstrap-vue@latest/dist/bootstrap-vue.js"></script>
   <div id="app">
     <b-form-checkbox-group
         v-model="formData.selectedBusinessLines"
         :options="formData.businessLines"
         value-field="id"
         text-field="name">
     </b-form-checkbox-group>
   </div>
   ```
2. `:options` will show the options based on the `text` key. Hence, You can tweak the objects which will have the keys as `text` and `value`.

- `value` : The selected value which will be set on `v-model`.
- `text` : Display text, or html Display basic inline html.

  Live Demo **:**

  ```js
  new Vue({  
    el: '#app',
    data() {
      return {
        formData: {
          selectedBusinessLines: [],
          businessLines: [
            {value: 1, text: 'Cars'},
            {value: 2, text: 'Trucks'}, 
            {value: 3, text: 'Buses'}
          ]
        }  
      }
    }            
  })
  ```

  ```html
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.3/vue.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https:////unpkg.com/bootstrap-vue@latest/dist/bootstrap-vue.js"></script>
  <div id="app">
    <b-form-checkbox-group
        v-model="formData.selectedBusinessLines"
        :options="formData.businessLines">
    </b-form-checkbox-group>
  </div>
  ```

You can have a look in this official documentation of [`<b-form-checkbox-group>`](https://bootstrap-vue.org/docs/components/form-checkbox)

Answer (score 0):

You need to structure your formData.businessLines that you use as options differently, like:

```
formData.businessLines = [
   { text: 'Cars', value: 1 },
   { text: 'Trucks', value: 2 },
   { text: 'Buses', value: 3 },
]
```

[See example 2 in the bootstrap-vue documentation](https://bootstrap-vue.org/docs/components/form-checkbox).